# How to write a query with "or" statements in iBATIS?

Tags: sql, mybatis, dynamic-sql, ibatis, data-persistence

I want to get data using a dynamic query or statement using iBATIS.

For example

```
select * from USERS where ID=1 or ID=12 or ID= 3 or ID=27.....
```

and I want to pass set of IDs as a List Object.

Comment: can you do like this `select * from USERS where ID IN ('1','12','3','27',...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cam use IN statement

```
<select id="selectKeys" parameterType="list"
        resultMap="selectKeysResultMap">
        SELECT COL1,COL2
        FROM
        TABLE1
        WHERE COL1 IN
        <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="("
            separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DataConnector add this;

```
Map<String,Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

Map<String,Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

inputMap.put("idList", idList);

mapper.getMcqAnswers(inputMap);
```

In your DBMapper.xml add this;

```
<select id="getMcqAnswers" resultType="your result type">

select id,answers from mcqs where id in

<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="idList" open="(" separator="," close=")">

${item}

</foreach>

</select>
```